# Sitefinity Widget User Control

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, sitefinity

I created this TransparencyControl and would like to be able to add it as a widget. I created this new MyWidget1 but I am not sure where or how to add the User Control? Should it be added to the cshtml page?

TransparencyControl.ascx

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TransparencyControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="SitefinityWebApp.transparency.TransparencyControl" %>
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="ucTransparency" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
    <asp:Xml ID="XmlForm" runat="server"></asp:Xml>
```

default.cshtml

```
@model SitefinityWebApp.Mvc.Models.MyWidget1Model

    <h1>
        @Html.Raw(Model.Message)
    </h1>
    <p>

        <uc:ucTransparency runat="server" ID="ucTransparency" />
    </p>
```

Comment: You can't put webforms user controls into MVC Views. Better is to implement your widget as MVC widget - meaning you need to create the controller as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Veselin said, you cannot mix MVC and user controls. You can either register your user control as a widget or use MVC to create the widget.

**Webforms:**

Have a look at the [webforms documentation](https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/newsrotator-widget-register-and-use-the-user-control-webforms) to see how you can register your user control.

**MVC**

If you are using MVC(which is recommended), Sitefinity has some [sample widgets](https://github.com/Sitefinity/mvc-samples) you can have a look at.

Note that after you implement new widgets, you must register them in the Sitefinity CMS toolbox. You do this by decorating the widget controller class with the `ControllerToolboxItem` attribute. Sitefinity has documentation on this which can be found [here](https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/register-new-widgets-in-sitefinity-cms-toolbox-mvc)

Comment: would I need to convert the user control into MVC widget?